# Default value for template function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Caution: I don't have C++11

I need a default value for a template function parameter, but it seems c++ 
will skip deduction for default parameters...

```
struct mode1 {};
struct mode2 {};

template <typename T>
void myFunc(int value, T mode = mode1())
{
    if(std::is_same<T, mode1>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "foo";
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T, mode2>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "bar";
    }
}
```

But how can i achieve, that this call will work:

```
myFunc(20); /* Defaults to mode1 */
```

Why i will use this? Because of optimization...
In my real life scenario, i would use this for this piece of code:

```
template <typename TokenType>
        HGStringBasic Tokenize(const _ElemT* tokens, size_type uTokenIndex, size_type uIndex = 0, size_type uEndIndex = npos, TokenType tokenType = tokenTypeChar()) const
        {           
            size_type uPosInStr;
            size_type uCurrToken;

            if(uEndIndex == npos)
            {
                uEndIndex = this->Length();
            }

            for( uCurrToken = 0 ; uIndex < uEndIndex ; (uIndex = uPosInStr+1), (++uCurrToken) )
            {
                if(std::is_same<TokenType, tokenTypeChar>::value)
                    uPosInStr = this->PosBrk(tokens, uIndex);
                else if(std::is_same<TokenType, tokenTypeString>::value)
                    uPosInStr = this->Pos(tokens, uIndex);

                if(uCurrToken == uTokenIndex) 
                {                       
                    if(uPosInStr == npos)
                        return this_type(&m_data[uIndex], uEndIndex - uIndex);
                    return this_type(&m_data[uIndex], (uPosInStr < uEndIndex ? uPosInStr : uEndIndex) - uIndex);
                }
                if(uPosInStr == npos)
                    break;
            }
            return this_type();
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If).

Comment: The correct way is to tag, not to add cautionary notes

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, i regret and will do it right next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, default value is not considered in [template arugment deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function default argument

You can add an overload, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void myFunc(int value, T mode)
{
    ...
}
void myFunc(int value) {
    myFunc(value, mode1());
}
```